# Distância em metros entre duas coordenadas usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gps

Podem me ajudar com a solução de um problema? Preciso calcular a distância em metros entre duas coordenadas de GPS. Porém preciso fazer isso usando o JavaScript puro.

O contexto disso é que a minha aplicação precisa validar a coordenada do cadastro de um cliente com a coordenada de marcação no momento da coleta do dado. Por exemplo:

- Coordenada cadastro cliente: **-23.522490;-46.736600**
- Coordenada marcação: **-23.4446654;-46.5319316**

Comparar as duas coordenadas e retornar a distância entre elas em metros.

Comment: Boa parte da fórmula eu ponho aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214587/64969; falta colocar a constante relativa ao raio da Terra e talvez normalizar z =]

Comment: Bem-vindo Genilson Soares, faça um tour pelo site começando por https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079 e antes da  próxima pergunta  leia esse post https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(position1, position2) {
    "use strict";
    var deg2rad = function (deg) { return deg * (Math.PI / 180); },
        R = 6371,
        dLat = deg2rad(position2.lat - position1.lat),
        dLng = deg2rad(position2.lng - position1.lng),
        a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.cos(deg2rad(position1.lat))
            * Math.cos(deg2rad(position1.lat))
            * Math.sin(dLng / 2) * Math.sin(dLng / 2),
        c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    return ((R * c *1000).toFixed());
}

var distancia = (getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(
   {lat: -23.522490, lng: -46.736600},
   {lat: -23.4446654, lng: -46.5319316}
));

console.log(distancia);
```

Veja outro calculo [**aqui**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-23.522490N%20-46.736600W%20to%20-23.4446654N%20-46.5319316W)

Esse  [**link**](http://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript) além de javascript tem em varias outras linguagens

Comment: Calculei em 2 sites diferentes e o resultado foi o mesmo: 22.6KM

Comment: @DvD Então está correta a formula da resposta, so falta arredondar para duas casas decimais

Comment: Tá sim, mas deixa assim pq ele quer em metros.

Comment: Aliás, seria melhor eliminar as decimais.

Comment: @DvD muita casa decimal  22590.197662552924 se ele marcar como aceita faço pra arredondar rs :)

Comment: `console.log((getDistanceFromLatLonInKm({lat: -23.522490, lng: -46.736600},{lat: -23.4446654, lng: -46.5319316})/1000).toFixed(1));` dá 22.6 certinho rs