# Como pegar a localização do usuário e comparar com outras para ver qual está mais próxima dele?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Preciso capturar a localização do usuário e comparar todos os locais citados em uma lista/array e ver qual está mais próximo e mostrar uma imagem do local. Até agora consegui tratar erros e localizar aonde o usuário está. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como eu posso prosseguir?

Abaixo tem o que já fiz:

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
        }
        else
        {
            x.innerHTML="Seu browser não suporta Geolocalização.";
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position)
    {
        x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
    }
    function showError(error)
    {
        switch(error.code)
        {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                x.innerHTML="Usuário rejeitou a solicitação de Geolocalização."
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                x.innerHTML="Localização indisponível."
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                x.innerHTML="A requisição expirou."
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                x.innerHTML="Algum erro desconhecido aconteceu."
                break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Acredito que a melhor forma de resolver esse problema é utilizando geohash. Dá uma olhada neste site: http://www.bigfastblog.com/geohash-intro

Comment: Existem alguns algoritmos prontos em javascript na internet que você pode usar como base.

Comment: Você pode transformar em cardinais, normalizar o `Z` e calcular a distância entre os dois pontos no espaço. Para elementos próximos, a influência da curvatura da Terra não irá afetar muito a distância relativa dos pontos. Quando se trata de coisas distantes (sei lá, mais de 2º?), a curvatura da Terra passa a ter um papel significativo e poderá interferir na ordenação relativa à distância. Veja [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214587/64969) como transformar coordenadas esféricas em cartesianas espaciais (não trato da normalização do `Z` entretanto)

Comment: @L.Cafezeiro poderia citar um como exemplo?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado poderia me passar algum site de exemplo? creio eu que não será tão complexo por se tratá apenas de localizações no Brasil

Comment: @Jorge a resposta que eu linkei já faz isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forma de resolver qual a distância entre dois pontos no mapa:

**1) Utilizando API Distance Matrix do Google**

Essa API é simples de utilizar e bastante eficiente. Provavelmente a melhor opção para quem quer calcular a distância entre os pontos levando em consideração as ruas (que é bem diferente da distância entre os pontos em linha reta). Porém, tem um limite para utilização grátis e para utilizar mais que a cota, tem que pagar. No entanto, se seu projeto terá pouco acesso, ou for financeiramente viável usar esta API, vá em frente!

Exemplo fornecido pela Google: https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

**2) Fórmula de Haversine - cálculo de distância entre pontos em linha reta**

Ótima opção para cálcular distância entre dois pontos, porém o cálculo deve ser executado para cada novos dois pontos existentes no mapa. Caso sua lista de pontos seja muito grande, pode ser um procedimento computacionalmente custoso e, consequentemente, demorado para os computadores clientes.

A forma de utilizar esta solução já foi explicada neste site: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1502821/7113404

**3) Geohash - cálculo de distância aproximada entre pontos em linha reta**

Geohash é um algoritmo criado por Gustavo Niemeyer e tem o objetivo de calcular distâncias entre posições no mapa. Essa solução não exige a realização de cálculos complexos no computador cliente. Além disto, pelo fato de não fazer um cálculo matemático para cada solicitação de valor de distância, é extremamente eficiente em cálculos de distância com muitos pontos cartesianos.

A proposta do algoritmo geohash é o seguinte:

1. Faça um corte vertical no mapa, dividindo-o em duas partes (no primeiro momento seria o equivalente a Greenwich) e dê ao hemisfério ocidental o bit 0, e ao hemisfério oriental o bit 1;
2. Faça em seguida um corte horizontal no mapa (no primeiro momento seria o equivalente a linha do equador), dividindo-o agora em quarto partes. Dê ao quadrado situado a posição equivalente ao noroeste os bits 00 (primeiro 0 indica a posição oeste, já o segundo 0 indica posição norte). Seguindo o padrão, os quadrados posicionados no nordeste, sudoeste e sudeste recebem os bits 01,11,10;
3. Repete esse procedimento até que cada pequeno quadrado seja representado por 32 bits.

A título de exemplo, ao final do algoritmo poderíamos ter a seguinte sequencia de bits representando um espaço no mapa:
0010110101011100011000110001101111000111, ou 
00101 10101 01110 00110 00110 00110 11110 00111, ou ainda,
utilizando a representação de caracteres (codificação de 32 bits):
  **5**(00101) **p**(10101) **f**(01110) **6**(00110) **6**(00110) **6**(00110) **y**(11110) **7**(00111)

Para saber a distância entre os pontos, deve-se comparar a geohash dos pontos da esquerda para direita. Quanto mais esses caracteres coincidirem, maior a proximidade entre os pontos. Já para saber quais os pontos que estão a uma determinada distância de um outro, basta calcular o geohash do ponto central e buscar os pontos que coincidem da esquerda para direita, considerando a tabela de aproximação de distâncias a seguir:

Geohash length  Cell width  Cell height
1   ≤ 5,000km   ×   5,000km
2   ≤ 1,250km   ×   625km
3   ≤ 156km ×   156km
4   ≤ 39.1km    ×   19.5km
5   ≤ 4.89km    ×   4.89km
6   ≤ 1.22km    ×   0.61km
7   ≤ 153m  ×   153m
8   ≤ 38.2m ×   19.1m
9   ≤ 4.77m ×   4.77m
10  ≤ 1.19m ×   0.596m
11  ≤ 149mm ×   149mm
12  ≤ 37.2mm    ×   18.6mm

Tabela retirada do site: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html

Um problema encontrado neste algoritmo acontece nos casos em que pontos que estão próximos ficam à margem de celulas (representada por uma string) diferentes. Por exemplo, imagine dois pontos próximos da Greenwich, porém um fica no hemisfério ocidental e outro oriental. Neste caso, a sequencia de caracteres gerada poderá erroneamente informar que os pontos estão mais distantes do que eles realmente estão. Para solucionar este problema, os algoritmos devem buscar os pontos em quadrados adjacentes.

Para exemplificar e tentar esclarecer ainda mais o tema, segue um algoritmo tirado do site http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html:

```
    /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
    /* Geohash encoding/decoding and associated functions   (c) Chris Veness 2014-2016 / MIT Licence  */
    /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */

    'use strict';


    /**
     * Geohash encode, decode, bounds, neighbours.
     *
     * @namespace
     */
    var Geohash = {};

    /* (Geohash-specific) Base32 map */
    Geohash.base32 = '0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz';

    /**
     * Encodes latitude/longitude to geohash, either to specified precision or to automatically
     * evaluated precision.
     *
     * @param   {number} lat - Latitude in degrees.
     * @param   {number} lon - Longitude in degrees.
     * @param   {number} [precision] - Number of characters in resulting geohash.
     * @returns {string} Geohash of supplied latitude/longitude.
     * @throws  Invalid geohash.
     *
     * @example
     *     var geohash = Geohash.encode(52.205, 0.119, 7); // geohash: 'u120fxw'
     */
    Geohash.encode = function(lat, lon, precision) {
        // infer precision?
        if (typeof precision == 'undefined') {
            // refine geohash until it matches precision of supplied lat/lon
            for (var p=1; p= lonMid) {
                    idx = idx*2 + 1;
                    lonMin = lonMid;
                } else {
                    idx = idx*2;
                    lonMax = lonMid;
                }
            } else {
                // bisect N-S latitude
                var latMid = (latMin + latMax) / 2;
                if (lat >= latMid) {
                    idx = idx*2 + 1;
                    latMin = latMid;
                } else {
                    idx = idx*2;
                    latMax = latMid;
                }
            }
            evenBit = !evenBit;

            if (++bit == 5) {
                // 5 bits gives us a character: append it and start over
                geohash += Geohash.base32.charAt(idx);
                bit = 0;
                idx = 0;
            }
        }

        return geohash;
    };


    /**
     * Decode geohash to latitude/longitude (location is approximate centre of geohash cell,
     *     to reasonable precision).
     *
     * @param   {string} geohash - Geohash string to be converted to latitude/longitude.
     * @returns {{lat:number, lon:number}} (Center of) geohashed location.
     * @throws  Invalid geohash.
     *
     * @example
     *     var latlon = Geohash.decode('u120fxw'); // latlon: { lat: 52.205, lon: 0.1188 }
     */
    Geohash.decode = function(geohash) {

        var bounds = Geohash.bounds(geohash); // =0; n--) {
                var bitN = idx >> n & 1;
                if (evenBit) {
                    // longitude
                    var lonMid = (lonMin+lonMax) / 2;
                    if (bitN == 1) {
                        lonMin = lonMid;
                    } else {
                        lonMax = lonMid;
                    }
                } else {
                    // latitude
                    var latMid = (latMin+latMax) / 2;
                    if (bitN == 1) {
                        latMin = latMid;
                    } else {
                        latMax = latMid;
                    }
                }
                evenBit = !evenBit;
            }
        }

        var bounds = {
            sw: { lat: latMin, lon: lonMin },
            ne: { lat: latMax, lon: lonMax },
        };

        return bounds;
    };


    /**
     * Determines adjacent cell in given direction.
     *
     * @param   geohash - Cell to which adjacent cell is required.
     * @param   direction - Direction from geohash (N/S/E/W).
     * @returns {string} Geocode of adjacent cell.
     * @throws  Invalid geohash.
     */
    Geohash.adjacent = function(geohash, direction) {
        // based on github.com/davetroy/geohash-js

        geohash = geohash.toLowerCase();
        direction = direction.toLowerCase();

        if (geohash.length === 0) throw new Error('Invalid geohash');
        if ('nsew'.indexOf(direction) == -1) throw new Error('Invalid direction');

        var neighbour = {
            n: [ 'p0r21436x8zb9dcf5h7kjnmqesgutwvy', 'bc01fg45238967deuvhjyznpkmstqrwx' ],
            s: [ '14365h7k9dcfesgujnmqp0r2twvyx8zb', '238967debc01fg45kmstqrwxuvhjyznp' ],
            e: [ 'bc01fg45238967deuvhjyznpkmstqrwx', 'p0r21436x8zb9dcf5h7kjnmqesgutwvy' ],
            w: [ '238967debc01fg45kmstqrwxuvhjyznp', '14365h7k9dcfesgujnmqp0r2twvyx8zb' ],
        };
        var border = {
            n: [ 'prxz',     'bcfguvyz' ],
            s: [ '028b',     '0145hjnp' ],
            e: [ 'bcfguvyz', 'prxz'     ],
            w: [ '0145hjnp', '028b'     ],
        };

        var lastCh = geohash.slice(-1);    // last character of hash
        var parent = geohash.slice(0, -1); // hash without last character

        var type = geohash.length % 2;

        // check for edge-cases which don't share common prefix
        if (border[direction][type].indexOf(lastCh) != -1 && parent !== '') {
            parent = Geohash.adjacent(parent, direction);
        }

        // append letter for direction to parent
        return parent + Geohash.base32.charAt(neighbour[direction][type].indexOf(lastCh));
    };


    /**
     * Returns all 8 adjacent cells to specified geohash.
     *
     * @param   {string} geohash - Geohash neighbours are required of.
     * @returns {{n,ne,e,se,s,sw,w,nw: string}}
     * @throws  Invalid geohash.
     */
    Geohash.neighbours = function(geohash) {
        return {
            'n':  Geohash.adjacent(geohash, 'n'),
            'ne': Geohash.adjacent(Geohash.adjacent(geohash, 'n'), 'e'),
            'e':  Geohash.adjacent(geohash, 'e'),
            'se': Geohash.adjacent(Geohash.adjacent(geohash, 's'), 'e'),
            's':  Geohash.adjacent(geohash, 's'),
            'sw': Geohash.adjacent(Geohash.adjacent(geohash, 's'), 'w'),
            'w':  Geohash.adjacent(geohash, 'w'),
            'nw': Geohash.adjacent(Geohash.adjacent(geohash, 'n'), 'w'),
        };
    };


    /* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  */
    if (typeof module != 'undefined' && module.exports) module.exports = Geohash; // CommonJS, node.js
```

fontes:

- http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html
- http://www.bigfastblog.com/geohash-intro
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash

Comment: inclua o seu código à resposta, o link que você está passando pode não estar disponível no futuro.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Como falei, não é meu código, é um exemplo disponível na internet. Sugiro que estude o quanto antes e crie seu próprio código. Meu objetivo foi de mostrar o caminho para estudo e não de fornecer código pronto.

Comment: @L.Cafezeiro então, citando o código e o link de origem, se você tiver direito de distribuição (normalmente open-source basta dar os créditos do autor original e, se tiver modificação, alguma coisa pra falar que houve adaptação) então bastaria colar o excerto interessante

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Entendo. Não era meu objetivo incluir código na resposta, porque são algoritmos grandes (vai dificultar a leitura) e bem fáceis de encontrar na web, em qualquer linguagem. Imagino que lembrar ao colega sobre a solução seja mais interessante (ao meu ver a melhor solução para a pegunta é geohash). De qualquer forma, ao interessado que fez a pergunta, o assunto é vasto na internet, tem muitos exemplos, e creio que não encontrará dificuldade de desenvolver seu próprio código. Vou remover o link na resposta. Abraço.

Comment: @Jorge Desculpe a falta de exemplos, Jorge. Ainda essa semana vou tentar melhorar esse post e tentar colocar exemplos de forma que fique mais didático e que ajude mais. Abraço!

Comment: @L.Cafezeiro Muito obrigado!! Estou no aguardo e conto com sua ajuda!! Abraço!

Comment: @Jorge, fiz uma atualização na resposta, espero que ajude mais. Abraço!

Comment: Muito bom @L.Cafezeiro, agora ficou bem mais fácil para eu seguir com o que preciso, muito obrigado pela ajuda! Abraço!